# JavaScript Date / Time

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following input and i can change the source of this data

Input

```
var strDate = "/Date(1391402871117+0100)/";
```

I can convert it to a date using eval, but i really dont want to eval

```
var DateResult1 = eval ("new Date(1391402871117+0100)");
console.log(DateResult1); // Date {Mon Feb 03 2014 05:47:51 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)}
```

I did try this, sadly do not work:

```
// Remove /Date( )/
strDate = strDate.replace(/[^\d+]/g,'');

var DateResult3 = new Date(strDate);
console.log(DateResult3); //Date {Invalid Date}
```

When i write result of strDate i manual with out " it work.

```
var DateResult2 = new Date(1391402871117+0100);
console.log(DateResult2); // Date {Mon Feb 03 2014 05:47:51 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)}
```

How can convert the input data into a date with out using eval or any library?

Comment: Very ugly solution `new Date(+"/Date(1391402871117+0100)/".slice(6, -2).split("+").reduce(function (a, b) { return +a + +b; }));`

Comment: This article may be of interest: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very likely not getting a correct result out of this code:

```
var DateResult2 = new Date(1391402871117+0100);
```

The problem is the addition: `1391402871117+0100`. `0100` is an *octal* constant, equal to `64` in decimal, which would add 64 milliseconds to the `1391402871117` timestamp. It *seems* likely to be indended as a time zone instead, but the `Date` constructor does not support time zones — only UTC and the local time zone of the browser.

Since UNIX timestamps are actually absolute (they are always in UTC), using just the timestamp would result in a `Date` instance referencing the correct *instant* in time, but possibly at another time zone. You can disregard the `+0100` part, by converting the `"1391402871117+0100"` into an integer using `parseInt`:

```
strDate = strDate.replace(/[^\d+]/g,'');
var DateResult2 = new Date(parseInt(strDate));
```

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but `1391402871117+0100` is same as `1391402871117+100` so if you don't parse octal as decimal it simply removes first 0.

Comment: The JS code itself is `new Date(1391402871117+0100)`. _You_ don't have to parse octal — the _Javascript engine_ of the browser does, and it indeed _does_ parse octal constants as octal. You can try it in the JS console: `0+0100` would give you `64`, not `100` as it would if the `0100` was parsed as decimal `100`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the data source, as you say, why not do this?

Have your data source generate something like this, to add the timezone offset to the timestamp:

```
// convert timezone offset hours into seconds and add them to the timestamp
return (unixTimestamp + (timezoneOffsetHours * 3600));
```

Then you can do something like this in your JS:

```
// Math.floor works faster than parseInt to convert a string to integer :)
var timestamp = Math.floor(result of above timestamp generation);
var DateResult = new Date(timestamp);
```

The reason:

`new Date()` can't handle timezones specified in this way (or at all as far as I can Google)

Answer (score 0):

try by parsing string to int:

```
var strDate = "/Date(1391402871117+0100)/";
strDate = strDate.replace(/[^\d+]/g, '');
var DateResult3 = new Date(parseInt(strDate.split('+')[0]) + parseInt(strDate.split('+')[1]));
console.log(DateResult3);
```

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YqR6e/)